# What type do arithmetic operators (+ - / *) have in PHP?

Tags: php, string, variables, types, integer

What type do arithmetic operators (+ - / *) have in PHP? I have such situation:

```
$argX= "1";
$argY = "2";
$operator = "+";
```

I want to add up two arguments using the operator in the variable. Smth like this:

```
$result = $argX $operator $argY;
```

I know that arguments are strings, so I convert them to numbers first.

```
$argX = $argX+0;
$argY = $argY+0;
```

But in what should I convert `$operator` to add the arguments using a value of `$operator` variable? How is it possible?

Comment: It doesn't work like that; operators don't have types.  In some other languages, they do (eg, Ruby or Scala), but not (AFAIK) PHP

Comment: the others are correct.  the operator is treated as a string, essentially the same thing as the letter "F" or the character "^" or even the character "|"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot use expressions for operators in PHP. Operators are operators, they don't have a type. You'll have to do something like this:

```
switch ($operator) {
    case '+' :  $result = $argX + $argY; break;
    case '-' :  $result = $argX - $argY; break;
    ...
}
```

You *could* `eval` it, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: You could just check the string to see it matches an allowed character (one of the operators) before doing `eval`

Answer (score 3):

you can't do that, however you could do

```
if($operator == '+')
{
    //math
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
// allowed operators
$allowed = array('+','-','/','*','%');

// check to see that operator is allowed and that the arguments are numeric
// so users can't inject cheeky stuff
if(in_array($operator, $allowed) && is_numeric($argX) && is_numeric($argY)){
    eval('<?php $result = '.$argX.' '.$operator.' '.$argY.'; ?>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a function named operator also work?

```
function operator($X, $Y) {
    $Z = $X + $Y;
    return $Z
}

$Z = operator($X,$Y);
```

Comment: function operator($X,$Y){                                                                          $Z = $x+$Y;                                                                                          return $Z;                                                                                                             }

Comment: When I first added the answer I realized that I had put it in the subject by accident and for some reason couldn't get edit to work. Thanks.